# How to get field from array and concatenate them into string (spark dataframe)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have array column

```
|-- packages: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- packageId: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- triggers: map (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- key: string
|    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How to get a new column with all **packageId**

example of column:

```
 "packages": [
        {
            "packageId": "package1",
            "triggers": {
                "1": "2"
            }
        },
       {
            "packageId": "package2",
            "triggers": {
                "1": "2",
                "2": "2"
            }
        }           
    ]
```

to

```
package1,package2
```

I used spark 2.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.withColumn("packageList", explode(df.col("packages").getField("packageId")))
  .groupBy(..)
  .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_set("packageList")))
```

Its work for me